# How to add multiple method titles to KnockoutJS ifnot statement in Magento2

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2

I am looking to add multiple shipping method titles to some knockout JS ifnot statement in Magento2. I currently have the following code which works for the method title listed.

`<!-- ko ifnot: method.method_title == 'UPS Prepaid Account' -->`

The other titles are UPS and Truck Delivery

`<!-- ko ifnot: method.method_title == 'UPS Prepaid Account','UPS','Truck Delivery' -->` is not working.

Comment: The part after `ifnot:` gets evaluated as regular javascript. So you could try `<!-- ko ifnot: ['UPS Prepaid Account','UPS','Truck Delivery'].includes(method.method_title) -->`